# How should operations be conducted at a towered airport that is in uncontrolled airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport

How should operations be conducted at an airport with an operating control tower that is in Class E (controlled) or Class G (uncontrolled) airspace? Is this topic covered in an FAA publication such as the Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM) or Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge (PHAC)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Airport with an operating control tower = talk to it.

From the regulations:

§91.126(d) (concerns Class G) and §91.127(c) (concerns Class E) are identical.

> *Communications with control towers.* Unless otherwise authorized or required by ATC, no person may operate an aircraft to, from, through, or on an airport having an operational control tower unless two-way radio communications are maintained between that aircraft and the control tower. Communications must be established prior to 4 nautical miles from the airport, up to and including 2,500 feet AGL. However, if the aircraft radio fails in flight, the pilot in command may operate that aircraft and land if weather conditions are at or above basic VFR weather minimums, visual contact with the tower is maintained, and a clearance to land is received. If the aircraft radio fails while in flight under IFR, the pilot must comply with §91.185.

Answer (score 5):

Treat a class E or class G tower just as you would Class D. The only differences are Basic VFR minimums, 4nm undepicted area, and IFR procedures